# Configuring to assign Private Network IP over PublicIP to the Pods in Istio

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio

I am facing an issue over the automatic assignment of Public IP(172.16/...) to the pods when I deploy the sample Bookinfo application in Istio.

Now that I am running on this application on cloud, Is there any way I can configure Istio(or Kubernetes) to assign the Private Network IP available for the pods rather than automatically assigning the PublicIP's as it used to in the local machine.

I understand in the local machine deployment there was only PublicIP available hence it was an automatic choice. But here we have the both Public and Private Network IP available for the pods, hence is there a possibility of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The IP assignment is a kubernetes not an istio feature and so you'd have to look there for how to configure it.

Istio should work either way - is there an issue you are seeing ?